# Multi-objective Optimization of Norm Functions

Tags: matlab

I am trying to perform a multi-objective optimization using MATLAB on two functions involving norms (shown in the image). The first function, *f<sub>1</sub>(**v**)*, is to be minimized and involves the 0-norm. The second function, *f<sub>2</sub>(**v**)*, is to be maximized and involves the 2-norm. Both **u** and **v** are vectors, however, **u** is fixed. The product **v**<sup>t</sup><sub>i</sub> . **u** produces a scalar. I am interested in generating the Pareto front for those two functions given a list of 10,000 different random vectors **v**<sub>i</sub>. Suggestions appreciated.[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempts to tackle this problem?

Comment: Yes, sure. However, what I managed to find so far is that MATLAB handles polynomials not objective functions of vectors as in my case. This is what the parameters for `fgoalattain` specify for example, whereas using `gamultiobj` is out of my scope! Reformulating the problem completely (to adapt to MATLAB's input) is something I want to avoid in the mean time.